# Errors after update Lubuntu 18.04 to 18.10

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, updates, lubuntu, 18.10

Today, I updated my Lubuntu 18.04 to 18.10 with the command:

> sudo do-release-upgrade

After some time I received message that the upgrade was successfully completed. After rebooting, I can see a black desktop, no task bar at the bottom, and that some thumbnails have disappeared from icons on the desktop. Is there any way to recover this to a normal state?

Comment: Did you follow the manual page on the topic? It should be noted that 18.04 is LXDE whereas 18.10 is LXQt and all the apps are different, so it's not like a normal upgrade and is bound to have issues. https://manual.lubuntu.me/D/upgrading.html

Answer (score 1):

Exact same thing happened to me.
You can restore the panel temporarily through these steps:
1. Press Ctrl+Alt+T to open a terminal
2. Type "lxpanel" without the quotes.

If the first step doesn't work, you need to do this first:
1. Right-click on your desktop, start a terminal.
2. sudo apt remove pcmanfm
3. sudo apt install pcmanfm-qt
4. Reboot.